# Formula for the Matrix Elements of the Inverse of special linear Universal R-Matrix of Uq(sln)

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

Motivated by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25423/the-inverse-of-a-universal-r-matrix-for-quantized-universal-enveloping-algebra-of), I'm going to ask a much more direct one: Let $R$ be a universal R-matrix for the quasitriangular Hopf algebra ${\cal U}_q ({\mathfrak sl}_N)$, $~$ $R ^{-1}$ its inverse, and $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ the dual pairing between ${\cal U}_q ({\mathfrak sl}_N)$ and $SU_q[N]$, do we have a formula for 
$$
\langle R^{-1},u^i_j \otimes u^r_s\rangle
$$
analogous to the formula
$$
\langle R,u^i_j \otimes u^r_s\rangle = q^{\delta_{ir}}\delta_{ij}\delta_{rs} + (q-q^{-1})\theta (i-r)\delta_{is}\delta_{jr},
$$
where $\theta$ denotes the Heaviside symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John, see my answer there.  It is as the OP thought.  The formula for $R^{-1}$ on the vector represenation can only be the inverse of the formula for $R$, namely

$\langle R^{-1},u^i_j\otimes u^r_s \rangle = q^{-1}(q^{-\delta_{ir}} \delta_{ij}\delta_{rs} + (q^{-1}-q)\theta(i-r)\delta(is)\delta(jr))$.

As I explained, the formula you wrote there is really for $q^{\frac 12} \langle R,u^i_j\otimes u^r_s \rangle$.

Comment: Thanks for that. Though I think that should an $R^{-1}$ in your centered line and not an $R$.
